# use eclipse classpath in ant tasks

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I want to use Ant to deliver a JAR file, how can I use the Eclipse classpath in my Ant task?

Greets,
Tobias

Comment: Note that this approach does not scale. Use instead a build framework supported by your IDE. For eclipse this could be maven.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [ant4eclipse](http://ant4eclipse.sourceforge.net/).