# Can I ask ANT to look into .classpath for external jars?

Tags: java, ant, build

Right now I have

```
<!-- Classpath declaration -->
 <path id="project.classpath">
  <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
   <include name="**/*.jar" />
   <include name="**/*.zip" />
  </fileset>    
 </path>


<!-- Compile Java source -->
 <target name="compile" depends="clean">
  <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
  <javac srcdir="${src.java.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" nowarn="on">
   <classpath refid="project.classpath" />
  </javac>
 </target>
```

Is there someway I can tell ANT to look into the eclipse's .classpath and figure out the external jars?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658467/use-eclipse-classpath-in-ant-tasks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is what you look for:

http://www.ant4eclipse.org/